# std::optional assignment operator in a constexpr context

Tags: c++, c++17, option-type, constexpr, libstdc++

I am scratching my head on `std::optional` which, according to [the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator%3D), shouldn't have a `constexpr` assignment operator.

However, when I try this snippet in gcc-8.1, it compiles and works just fine:

```
constexpr std::optional<int> foo() {
    std::optional<int> bar = 3;
    bar = 1337;
    return bar;
}

constexpr auto z = foo();
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Does `constexpr auto z = foo()` compile also?

Comment: @Evgeny Yes, it does, it worked in a more complex context...

Comment: @Evgeny Yes, live: https://godbolt.org/z/Y11f6k

Comment: See [P0602](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0602r3.html). It‘s not applied to the standard yet, but when it's applied, it will make the assignment `constexpr`. (And it's expected to apply retroactively to C++17.)

Comment: @cpplearner Ah, that explains a lot! Please, post it as an answer, I will accept it as that's the correct one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like this is a bug in gcc. I just tried in clang-6.0 and the compilation fails with the expected error. Also, the standard doesn't mention any `constexpr` overload for the assignment operator, thus I'll report this bug to gcc bugtracker.

[Link to the bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87016)

---

**Edit:**

It turned out that this is not a bug in gcc, but a mistake in the standard:

> > I don't understand how the code snippet can work in a constexpr context when the current c++17 standard doesn't specify any constexpr assignment operator.
>
> That's true, but the standard is broken.
>
> All implementations define the assignment operator as defaulted, and so the compiler makes it constexpr.
>
> In fact the [P0602R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0602r3.html) proposal is relevant, because it would **require** implementations to define the operator as defaulted (in order to be trivial) and so the compiler is always going to make it constexpr for std::optional.
>
> I've raised this with the standards committee.

You can read more about it in [the bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87016#c5).

Comment: no, it doesn't fail with clang-6.0 either: https://wandbox.org/permlink/o7gn4bGMdazVGqUB

Comment: neither does VS2017

Comment: @AndriyTylychko That's even weirder because here it fails: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/2u3u3M

Comment: I checked `<optional>` in VS and yes `operator=` is not `constexpr`, so my guess is that it's not involved at all. Can it be that it's optimised out?

Comment: @AndriyTylychko I'm not sure, I've tried compiling with `-std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O0 -g -fno-elide-constructors` and the compilation was still successful.

Comment: interesting. and we have another mystery - why wandbox and godbolt show different results both claiming to use clang-6.0. unfortunately I don't have clang locally to check who's right

Comment: @AndriyTylychko I am wondering about the same... I just tried compiling it with clang-6.0.1 on my laptop (Linux laptop 4.17.11-arch1 x86_64) and it compiles, too. This is really bugging me.

Comment: I posted the bug report, we will see what the developers will say about it.